# Get the value of a variable in a module ruby

Tags: ruby, module

If I have a module named "Mod1" and it has a variable that is calculated.  Now if I have a script file that calls this module how can I puts the value of the variable within the module?  Or better yet, if the variable is an array, how can I iterate through that variable?

Thanks!

Here's the code within my main script where I'm setting up the module:

```
require_relative 'modules/Mod1'
```

Here's my module:

```
module Mod1
  @passes = []
  def self.passes(file)
    @passes.push(file)
  end
end
```

So from my main script I am able to run Mod1.passes("name1") and Mod1.passes("name2"), I then want to be able to iterate through the values of passes like:

```
Mod1.passes.each do |pass|
  puts pass
end
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: show your module first.. how you created ? What do you mean by variable ? Is it `ivar`, `cvar`, `gvar` etc... ?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your method to act like a getter depending on its argument:

```
module Mod1
  @passes = []
  def self.passes(file=nil)
    file.nil? ? @passes : @passes.push(file)
  end
end
```

The examples from your question will then work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have said, the correct solution depends on the type of variable in your module.

```
module Mod1
  @foo = :bar
end

Mod1.instance_eval("@foo")
```

A better approach might be to monkey patch a getter method into the module by reopening it:

```
module Mod1
  def self.get_passes
    @passes
  end
end
```

Now you can get the `@passes` by calling `Mod1.get_passes`